# Can I decorate advanced PowerShell functions with my own custom attributes?

Tags: powershell, function, attributes

For example:

```
function TestThis()
{
    [MySpecialCustomAttribute]
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(...)
    Process{...}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes, of course you can!

Any type derived from `Attribute` which allows `UsageType.All` (or `UsageType.Class`) can be used on the function itself (i.e. above `Param`)

Any type derived from `Attribute` which allows `UsageType.Property` or `UsageType.Field` usage can be used on parameters themselves or variables.

It's not uncommon to just be lazy and use `UsageType.All` (e.g. the built in `OutputType` attribute does that).

### You can even write them in PowerShell classes now

```
using namespace System.Management.Automation
class ValidateFileExistsAttribute : ValidateArgumentsAttribute {
    [void] Validate([object]$arguments, [EngineIntrinsics]$engineIntrinsics) {
        if($null -eq $arguments) {
            throw [System.ArgumentNullException]::new()
        }
        if(-not (Test-Path -Path "$arguments" -Type Leaf)) {
            throw [System.IO.FileNotFoundException]::new("The specified path is not a file: '$arguments'")
        }        
    }
}
```

See [more examples](https://powershellexplained.com/2017-02-20-Powershell-creating-parameter-validators-and-transforms/) on [Kevin Marquette](https://powershellexplained.com/2017-02-19-Powershell-custom-attribute-validator-transform/)'s blog.

There's [an older example here](https://web.archive.org/web/20110714172607/http://huddledmasses.org/better-error-messages-for-powershell-validatepattern/) showing how to do it in PowerShell 4 and earlier using Add-Type, although it's a little out of date now, because the particular example it shows has been integrated into PowerShell 6 and is no longer needed

There are also [videos](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/MsftPowerShell/PowerShell-v5-Classes--Property-Validation-Attributes)

Comment: Link is dead, please include the solution here

Comment: Not what I was looking for, but just in case this is of interest to someone, [here is a wayback machine archived version of the page](https://web.archive.org/web/20110714172607/http://huddledmasses.org/better-error-messages-for-powershell-validatepattern/)