# decorating a powershell function

Tags: powershell

In a Powershell module, can you decorate a function with custom attribute so that you can run Get-Command -Module (or something similar) to get a subset of functions based on user criteria?

The nearest related question I found was this:
[Can I decorate advanced PowerShell functions with my own custom attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101391/can-i-decorate-advanced-powershell-functions-with-my-own-custom-attributes)

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own attributes but Get-Command won't know anything about them.  However you can write your own function to get functions with the specified attribute e.g.:

```
Get-Command -Module <moduleName> -CommandType Function | 
    Where {$_.Scriptblock.Attributes.TypeId.Name -match 'CmdletBindingAttribute'}
```

Note that this uses the member enumeration feature of PowerShell v3.  If you are on V2 You will need to do this:

```
Get-Command -Module <moduleName> -CommandType Function | 
    Where {$_.Scriptblock.Attributes | Foreach {$_.TypeId.Name -match 'CmdletBindingAttribute'}}
```

BTW another way to get a subset of functions is to use the criteria of verb and noun e.g.:

```
Get-Command -Module <moduleName> Get-*
Get-Command -Module <moduleName> *-SomeNoun
```